# EaselJS: change shape fill color on mouse click

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

I'm having an hard time working with EaselJS. Basically I want to create a simple grid and highlight the actual element selected:

```
var stageWidth = 800,
   stageHeight = 600,
   cell_size = 50,
   w = 16,
   h = 12,
   n = w * h,
   canvas,
   stage,
   background;

$(document).ready(function(){

            canvas = $("#container")[0];     
            stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

            var x_pos = 0,
                y_pos = 0,
                res = 0,
                grid_el;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++){

                res = i%w;

                if(i>0){
                    if(res===0){
                        x_pos = 0;
                        y_pos++;
                    } else {
                        x_pos++;
                    }
                }

                grid_el = new createjs.Shape();
                grid_el.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2,"square").beginStroke("#000000");
                grid_el.graphics.beginFill("#70FF85");
                grid_el.graphics.rect(x_pos * cell_size,y_pos * cell_size,cell_size,cell_size);
                grid_el.x_pos = x_pos * cell_size;
                grid_el.y_pos = y_pos * cell_size;
                grid_el.name = "quad";

                stage.addChild(grid_el);
            }

            stage.update();

            stage.onMouseDown = function(e){
                console.log(e);
                var quad = this.getObjectsUnderPoint(e.stageX,e.stageY);

                var clone = quad[0].graphics.clone();
                clone.beginFill("#51D9FF");

                quad[0].graphics = new createjs.Graphics(clone);

                stage.update();
            }

        });
```

I tried cloning the actual element graphics property, changing the fill color and then updating the stage, but I only obtain a white element, just like it didn't recognize the new graphics properties.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I would recommend is using the onMouseOver/onMouseOut calls backs on a the shape or display object that you are creating.
When you can update you color that was.

Here is a simple demo that might help illustrate my point.

[Link to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sebastian_derossi/PYxu7/)

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("test");
createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
stage.enableMouseOver(10);
var padding = 1;
var width = 55;
var height = 55;
var cols = 15;
for(var i=0;i<200;i++) {
    var s = new createjs.Shape();
    s.overColor = "#3281FF"
    s.outColor = "#FF0000"
    s.graphics.beginFill(s.outColor).drawRect(0, 0, width, height).endFill();
    s.x = (width + padding) * (i%cols);
    s.y = (height + padding) * (i/cols|0);
    s.onMouseOver = handleMouseOver;
    s.onMouseOut = handleMouseOut;
    stage.addChild(s)
}

createjs.Ticker.addListener(stage);

function handleMouseOver(event) {
   var target = event.target;
   target.graphics.clear().beginFill(target.overColor).drawRect(0, 0, width, height).endFill();
}

function handleMouseOut(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    target.graphics.clear().beginFill(target.outColor).drawRect(0, 0, width, height).endFill();
}

function tick() {
  stage.update();   
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well it's been a while since I asked this question and meanwhile I used some work-around-code to get it work. Anyway this seem a better solution, so I will try to adapt my function :) Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1):

Might consider going with KineticJS, you would just do:

```
circle.on('click', function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

I believe KineticJS is the only canvas framework that mirrors the DOM event model (you can bind events to nodes, they can bubble, you can leverage event delegation, etc.)

Comment: Yes, we discover Kinetic a while after we started this project, maybe it's better in some aspects but we actually are too far in the development phase to switch our Canvas engine. Thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: Thanks...I might switch.  I'm finding CreateJS VERY difficult to work with